# fixed-width inside gutters using Susy-Sass

Tags: fixed, fluid-layout, susy-sass

I am new to Susy and really like what I am seeing but I tried to set gutters to inside fixed and it doesn't seem to like it.
I really like my gutters to match my vertical margins.
Someone please point me to the settings to get this effect.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/578f74196db07f8868cb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `gutter-position: inside-static`, and also a `column-width` setting. The static gutter size will be calculated from the column-width.